# "Error generating solution file in temporary directory" while creating Subsite template

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, site-template

I am trying to take the template from one of the subsite but it's not allowing me to take it and throwing below error as Exception calling “Save as Template” with 4 argument(s):

> Error generating solution file in temporary directory.

I tried checking if there is some issue with site level features but there is no custom feature, it's a Team site not even a publishing site. Also checked if there can be some issue with list at site but it's seems to be correct and working fine. Please suggest the possible cause behind it or how can I approach to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give app pool account access to the c:\users\Administrator\AppData\local\temp directory and check again.

Or run the command: Psconfig -cmd securresources.

If the issue exists, save other sites/subsites to as template to check again.